# innerHTML is not displaying new variables set with event handlers

Tags: javascript, html, css

This code displays two color options (blue and yellow) and two transport options (car and bike). Below this is a div in which I would like to display, with innerHTML, which color and transport options the user has clicked. The variables have been initialized to `color: yellow` and `transport:plane`. When blue and car are clicked, nothing displays below.

However, when I click the blue and car boxes, the console then indicates that the variables have been changed to blue and car (from their starting values of yellow and plane). And if I initialize the variables to blue and car, the innerHTML portion seems to work.

```js
// initialize variables 
let color = 'yellow';
let transport = 'plane';

// colors 
const blue = document.querySelector('.blue');
const yellow = document.querySelector('.yellow');
const car = document.querySelector('.car');
const bike = document.querySelector('.bike');

// innerHTML block if car = blue and transport = car
const blueCar = `<p>This is a blue car</p>`;

// location where innerHTML block will be applied 
const output = document.querySelector('.output');


// event listeners and functions applied to blue and car
blue.addEventListener('click', addBlue);

function addBlue() {
  color = 'blue';
}

car.addEventListener('click', addCar);

function addCar() {
  transport = 'car';
}

// conditional statement 
if (color == 'blue' && transport == 'car') {
  output.innerHTML = blueCar;
}
```

```css
.blue {
  font-size: 1rem;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}

.blue:hover {
  background-color: blue;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.yellow {
  font-size: 1rem;
  border: 2px solid yellow;
}

.car {
  font-size: 1rem;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.car:hover {
  background-color: grey;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.bike {
  font-size: 1rem;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<!-- color options, for user to click -->
<div class="blue">blue</div>
<div class="yellow">yellow</div>

<!-- transport options, for user to click  -->
<div class="car">car</div>
<div class="bike">bike</div>

<!-- display clicked color and transport options -->
<div class="output"></div>
```

Comment: Put the if statement inside the event handler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try use in function this code.

```
if (color == 'blue' && transport == 'car') {
    output.innerHTML = blueCar; 
}
```

Try replacing with.

```
function renderOutput() {
  // conditional statement 
  if (color == 'blue' && transport == 'car') {
    output.innerHTML = blueCar; 
  } 
}

renderOutput();
```

Example code: https://codepen.io/yasgo/pen/eYyaaZz

This is what you wanted to do?

Comment: Consider removing the link to the code pen and putting this directly into a snippet in your answere

Answer (score 2):

You only check your condition once when the page loads for the first time

```
// conditional statement 
if (color == 'blue' && transport == 'car') {
output.innerHTML = blueCar; 
}
```

You need to check this condition after you click on each of the buttons.
You can also create a function

```
checkIfBlueCar() ...
```

where you will check the condition and return a boolean on the result

Answer (score 1):

```js
// initialize variables 
let color = 'yellow';  
let transport = 'plane'; 

// colors 
const blue = document.querySelector('.blue'); 
const yellow = document.querySelector('.yellow'); 
const car = document.querySelector('.car'); 
const bike = document.querySelector('.bike');

// innerHTML block if car = blue and transport = car
const blueCar = `<p>This is a blue car</p>`; 

// location where innerHTML block will be applied 
const output = document.querySelector('.output'); 


// event listeners and functions applied to blue and car
blue.addEventListener('click', addBlue); 
function addBlue() {
  color = 'blue';  
  render()
}

car.addEventListener('click', addCar); 
function addCar() {
  transport = 'car'; 
  render()
}

// conditional statement 
function render() {
  if (color == 'blue' && transport == 'car') {
    output.innerHTML = blueCar; 
  } 
}

render()
```

```css
.blue {
    font-size: 1rem;
    border:  2px solid blue;
}
.blue:hover {
    background-color:  blue;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.yellow {
    font-size: 1rem;
    border:  2px solid yellow;
}
.car {
    font-size: 1rem;
    border:  2px solid black;
}
.car:hover {
    background-color: grey;
    cursor:  pointer;
}
.bike {
    font-size:  1rem;
    border:  2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<!-- color options, for user to click -->
<div class="blue">blue</div>
<div class="yellow">yellow</div>

<!-- transport options, for user to click  -->
<div class="car">car</div>
<div class="bike">bike</div>

<!-- display clicked color and transport options -->
<div class="output"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is your conditional is running before the event handlers for the clicks run since it is outside the function(s)

To resolve this you need to do that inside the click event handler function

```
if (color == 'blue' && transport == 'car') {
  output.innerHTML = blueCar;
}
```

I did that here by putting a new function in place and calling it and passing it the variables with the values:
`updateVisible(transport, color);`

I get a sense you are learning so I would suggest making your code a bit more "DRY" and use code that would not repeat itself. You can also store the values you wish to use right on the element in a data attribute and thus use less global variables which is a good thing to do.
Here is an example of that, click around and see what it does.

```js
const transports = document.querySelectorAll('.transport');
const colors = document.querySelectorAll('.color');
const output = document.querySelector('.output');

function changeTransport(event) {
  let transport = this.dataset.transport;
  let color = output.dataset.color;
  output.dataset.transport = transport;
  updateVisible(transport, color);
}

function changeColor(event) {
  let transport = output.dataset.transport;
  let color = this.dataset.value;
  output.dataset.color = color;
  updateVisible(transport, color);
}

function updateVisible(newtrans, color) {
  output.innerHTML = showChange(newtrans, color);
}

function showChange(transport, color) {
  return `<p style="color:${color};">This is a ${color} ${transport}</p>`;
}

transports
  .forEach((element) => element.addEventListener('click', changeTransport));

colors
  .forEach((element) => element.addEventListener('click', changeColor));
```

```css
.color {
  font-size: 1rem;
  border: 2px solid;
}

.color:hover {
  background-color: #ddffdd;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.transport:hover {
  background-color: #D0D0D0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.transport {
  border: solid 1px green;
  margin-top: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<!-- color options, for user to click -->
<div class="color" data-type="color" data-value="blue">blue</div>
<div class="color" data-type="color" data-value="yellow">yellow</div>
<div class="color" data-type="color" data-value="pink">Pink</div>
<div class="color" data-type="color" data-value="orange">Orange</div>
<div class="color" data-type="color" data-value="purple">Purple</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="transport" data-transport="car">car</div>
  <div class="transport" data-transport="bike">bike</div>
  <div class="transport" data-transport="plane">Plane</div>
  <div class="transport" data-transport="baloon">Up in the Air</div>
  <div class="transport" data-transport="Mule">Ride Mules</div>
</div>
<!-- display clicked color and transport options -->
<div data-color="cyan" data-transport="hay wagon" class="output"></div>
```